# R: fill values to columns as mean of selected columns (step = 12) from another dataframe

Tags: r, reshape, panel-data

I have a dataframe that has observations of climate data, vary from January 1980 to December 1990. The dataset looks like this:

[image]

My objective is to get a dataset where the first 4 columns to be the same as those in my original dataset, and the rest to be monthly average values across all years.
[image]

Since the mean of each month is calculated as the average value of (all of) every 12 columns, I have a rough idea of using the mode of the column index being divided by 12. And the common mode defines the columns used for the calculation. For example, for January's value, tave01, the value in the new dataframe is calculated of all columns from the original dataframe where the mode of Index/12 = 5.

Anyone has an idea on how to do it? I wrote the codes below to build the framework for the original dataframe and the dataframe I want:

```
df_original <- data.frame(matrix(,nrow = 155, ncol = 484))
colnames(df_original)[1:10] <- c('ID','latitude','longitude','elevation','198001','198002','198003','198004','198005','198006') #original dataset, the variable names are months from 1980-01 to 1990-12. 
col_ind <- seq(5,length(colnames(tave)));col_ind #sequence of column indecies


df_new <- data.frame(matrix(,nrow = nrow(df_original), ncol = 16)) #empty new dataframe
df_new[,1:4] <- df_original[,1:4]
colnames(df_new) <- c('ID','latitude','longitude','elevation','tave01','tave02','tave03','tave04','tave05','tave06','tave07','tave08','tave09','tave10','tave11','tave12')
```

Comment: You could use `month_cols <- paste0(rep(1980:2019, each = 12), stringr::str_pad(1:12, 2, pad = "0")); colnames(df_original) <- c('ID','latitude','longitude','elevation', month_cols)` to generate the column names for the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach where I reshape, convert the header name into year and month columns, then take the location mean for each month, and reshape that wide again.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_original %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(1:4)) %>%
  separate(name, c("year", "month"), sep = 4) %>%
  group_by(ID, latitude, longitude, elevation, month) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = month, names_glue = "tave{month}", values_from = avg)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 1 × 16
  ID    latitude longitude elevation tave01 tave02 tave03 tave04 tave05 tave06 tave07 tave08 tave09 tave10 tave11 tave12
  <lgl> <lgl>    <lgl>     <lgl>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 NA    NA       NA        NA            NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```